# Generate scripts wizard hangs when loading database information

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, scripting

I am trying to script out a database from an instance of SQL Server 2017, so I can load it into an instance of SQL Server 2014. I right-clicked on the database, chose  Tasks -> Generate Scripts, and the "Generate and Publish Scripts" wizard popped up, showing the following...

[image: Scripts wizard]

The problem is that it just sits there, with the progress bar whizzing along, but apparently not doing anything. The Task Manager shows very little CPU or memory being used, but it never gets past this stage. I left it overnight, and it was still there about 14 hours later.

The database has 62 tables, and a backup file is about 750Mb, so it's not that big.

I tried clicking the "Set scripting options" link on the left and continuing from there, but when it tried to generate the script, it gave an error...

[image: Wizard error]

I presume this is because it hadn't loaded the database information.

Anyone any ideas? I need to get this database loaded, but as the target machine is a lower version, I can't restore a backup.

Comment: Use sp_whoisactive to see if something is blocking it.

Comment: Does it happen with any database you try to generate scripts? Is there any error log on event viewer or sql server log?

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the comments. As it happens, we ended up with the database being unavailable, and the business owner decided it was worth reinstalling Windows (well overdue). We have recent backups, so scrubbed the machine and are currently reinstalling. I'll see what happens when it's back up. Thanks again.

Comment: Reinstalling did the trick. Went past the first page of the wizard in a few seconds. Thanks again.